# Connecting from sqlite database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing problem with connecting with the SQLite database, instead of MySQL.

Can anyone please tell me the procedure to connect with the SQLite database from Rails.

Thanks in advance.

Anu.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow [these instructions](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/sqlite).